# finding elements in array which are following a certain value in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing, element

assuming I have an array:

```
[1 5 1 1 3 1 1 1 7]
```

and I want to find the index of every element which follows a '1', so I would get 2, 5, 9. Does matlab provide anything to do so?
Thanks for you help, Nadine

Comment: If there is always only one element in between ones as in the example that you've given, you can simply use: `B= find(array~=1)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest the following one-liner:

```
a = [1 5 1 1 3 1 1 1 7];
idx = find(a(1:end-1) == 1 & a(2:end) ~= 1) + 1
```

returns:

```
idx =

     2     5     9
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way. Let `x` be the input vector.

```
result = find(diff(x==1)<0)+1;
```

Example:

```
>> x = [1 5 1 1 3 1 1 1 7];
>> result = find(diff(x==1)<0)+1
result =
     2     5     9
```